# How to loop through gridview client side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, telerik

I have a grid view like this :

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="true"
        PageSize="20" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" Width="500px">
        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
        <MasterTableView TableLayout="Fixed" Width="500px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# (((GridItem)Container).ItemIndex != 0)? "</td></tr></table>" : "" %>
                <asp:Panel ID="ItemContainer" CssClass='<%# (((GridItem)Container).ItemType == GridItemType.Item)? "item" : "alternatingItem" %>'
                    runat="server">
                    <asp:Image ID="image_event" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("event_pic")%>' AlternateText="" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtn_map" runat="server" onclientclick="adjustSelected(this)" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </MasterTableView>
        <GroupingSettings CaseSensitive="false" />
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

---

I wanna through client side method `adjustSelected(this)` to loop through all the radiobuttons make them unselected and set the clicked one only selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give all those radio buttons in the grid a class (`class="radioClass"`):

```
<asp:RadioButton CssClass="radioClass" runat="server" onclientclick="adjustSelected(this)" />
```

Then use the class to select all others radios:

```
function adjustSelected(obj){
    $('.radioClass').prop('checked', false);
    this.checked = true;
}
```

You can also use unobtrusive JavaScript:

```
var $radios = $('.radioClass');
$('.radioClass').click(function(){
    $radios.prop('checked', false);
    this.checked = true;
});
```

---

**Update:**

O.k. ASP.Net generate weird markup, so use this as the function:

```
function adjustSelected(obj){
    console.log($('.radioClass :radio'));
    $('.radioClass :radio').prop('checked', false);
    $(':radio', obj).prop('checked', true);
}​
```

Comment: @just_name. Did you give all the radios a class like I did... I guess not. `class="radioClass"`

Comment: @just_name. It doesn't make sense, there is something else going on. Can you show me the **rendered** Grid, with two rows?

Comment: @just_name. It's probably because you need to write `cssClass` instead of `class` in ASP.net, but I didn't used it for a long time ago...

Comment: @just_name. I'll give you a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNdjB/1). Check your markup. That `onclientclick` should be `onclick`.

Comment: @just_name. Not in the code you gave me, anyway it works, because the event bubbles up the dom. Your [fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNdjB/8/)

Comment: @just_name. Create a fiddle with the complete code. It's like the 10th time I answer your questions... Let me see what you really got, then we shall see.

Comment: @just_name and gdoron - could these comments be deleted now?

Comment: @Kev. Please! Please! yes... :)

Comment: @gdoron : really i appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 function checkRadio{
    var grid = document.getElementById('<%=RadGrid1.ClientID%>');
    if (grid) {
        var elements = grid.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var checkcount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].type == 'radio' && elements[i].id.toString().match('rbtn_map') != null) {
               --- do code here ---                    
            }
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: He's using jQuery, it could be so nice and clean... :)